# How to tell when your iPhone audio is being rerouted to an external device?

Tags: ios, core-audio, external-accessory

I would like to be notified when my iPhone's audio is being re-routed to another device , say if I connect it to an external Hi-fi system (an MFi device).  Put another way, how do I detect if the audio is playing from my iPhone vs. another device when it happens?

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Apple's Audio Session documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingRouteChanges/HandlingRouteChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH12-SW1) on how to request and handle Audio Session route change notifications, and what kind of audio notifications are possible.